# Client application crash causes Server to crash? (C++)

Tags: c++, sockets, client

I'm not sure if this is a known issue that I am running into, but I couldn't find a good search string that would give me any useful results.
Anyway, here's the basic rundown:

we've got a relatively simple application that takes data from a source (DB or file) and streams that data over TCP to connected clients as new data comes in. its a relatively low number of clients; i would say at max 10 clients per server, so we have the following rough design:

client: connect to server, set to read (with timeout set to higher than the server heartbeat message frequency). It blocks on read.

server: one listening thread that accepts connections and then spawns a writer thread to read from the data source and write to the client. The writer thread is also detached(using boost::thread so just call the .detach() function). It blocks on writes indefinetly, but does check errno for errors before writing. We start the servers using a single perl script and calling "fork" for each server process.

The problem(s):
at seemingly random times, the client will shutdown with a "connection terminated (SUCCESFUL)" indicating that the remote server shutdown the socket on purpose. However, when this happens the SERVER application ALSO closes, without any errors or anything. it just crashes.

Now, to further the problem, we have multiple instances of the server app being started by a startup script running different files and different ports. When ONE of the servers crashes like this, ALL the servers crash out.

Both the server and client using the same "Connection" library created in-house. It's mostly a C++ wrapper for the C socket calls.

here's some rough code for the write and read function in the Connection libary:

```
int connectionTimeout_read = 60 * 60 * 1000; 
int Socket::readUntil(char* buf, int amount) const
    {
        int readyFds = epoll_wait(epfd,epEvents,1,connectionTimeout_read);
        if(readyFds < 0)
        {
            status = convertFlagToStatus(errno);
            return 0;
        }
        if(readyFds == 0)
        {
            status = CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
            return 0;
        }
        int fd = epEvents[0].data.fd;
        if( fd != socket)
        {
            status = CONNECTION_INCORRECT_SOCKET;
            return 0;
        }
        int rec = recv(fd,buf,amount,MSG_WAITALL);

        if(rec == 0)
            status = CONNECTION_CLOSED;
        else if(rec < 0)
            status = convertFlagToStatus(errno);
        else
            status = CONNECTION_NORMAL;
        lastReadBytes = rec;
        return rec;

    }



int Socket::write(const void* buf, int size) const
    {

        int readyFds = epoll_wait(epfd,epEvents,1,-1);
        if(readyFds < 0)
        {
            status = convertFlagToStatus(errno);
            return 0;
        }
        if(readyFds == 0)
        {
            status = CONNECTION_TERMINATED;
            return 0;
        }
        int fd = epEvents[0].data.fd;
        if(fd != socket)
        {
            status = CONNECTION_INCORRECT_SOCKET;
            return 0;
        }
        if(epEvents[0].events != EPOLLOUT)
        {
            status = CONNECTION_CLOSED;
            return 0;
        }
        int bytesWrote = ::send(socket, buf, size,0);
        if(bytesWrote < 0)
            status = convertFlagToStatus(errno);
        lastWriteBytes = bytesWrote;
        return bytesWrote;

    }
```

Any help solving this mystery bug would be great! at the VERY least, I would like it to NOT crash out the server even if the client crashes (which is really strange for me, since there is no two-way communication).

Also, for reference, here is the server listening code:

```
while(server.getStatus() == connection::CONNECTION_NORMAL)
        {
            connection::Socket s = server.listen();
                if(s.getStatus() != connection::CONNECTION_NORMAL)
                {
                    fprintf(stdout,"failed to accept a socket. error: %s\n",connection::getStatusString(s.getStatus()));
                }

                DATASOURCE* dataSource;
                dataSource = open_datasource(XXXX);  /* edited */               if(dataSource == NULL)
                {
                    fprintf(stdout,"FATAL ERROR. DATASOURCE NOT FOUND\n");
                    return;
                }
                    boost::thread fileSender(Sender(s,dataSource));
                    fileSender.detach();


        }
```

...And also here is the spawned child sending thread:

```
::signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_IGN);

    //const int headerNeeds = 29;
    const int BUFFERSIZE = 2000;
    char buf[BUFFERSIZE];

    bool running = true;
    while(running)
    {
             memset(buf,'\0',BUFFERSIZE*sizeof(char));
        unsigned int readBytes = 0;
        while((readBytes = read_datasource(buf,sizeof(unsigned char),BUFFERSIZE,dataSource)) == 0)
        {
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000));
        }
        socket.write(buf,readBytes);
        if(socket.getStatus() != connection::CONNECTION_NORMAL)
            running = false;

    }
    fprintf(stdout,"socket error: %s\n",connection::getStatusString(socket.getStatus()));
    socket.close();
    fprintf(stdout,"sender exiting...\n");
```

Any insights would be welcome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nik You should accept some of the answers to your previous questions if you want more people to help you out. A 0% is going to put off a lot of potential suitors.

Comment: What operating system? Got any core dumps? (go fish)

Comment: @chrisaycock just accepted the previous threads, thanks.

Comment: @bmargulies here's what uname -a prints: Linux krma01d 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 21 10:44:23 EST 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux 

no core dumps, i'm also wrapping the actual code with try / catch blocks to at least see if i get ANYthing, but so far nothing...

Comment: Run server in gdb and await developments, or make sure that ulimit for coresize is nonzero and see if you are get a core dump.

Comment: @bmargulies will try running in gdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've *probably* got everything backwards... when the server crashes, the OS will close all sockets.  So the server crash happens first and causes the client to get the disconnect message (FIN flag in a TCP segment, actually), the crash is not a result of the socket closing.

Since you have multiple server processes crashing at the same time, I'd look at resources they share, and also any scheduled tasks that all servers would try to execute at the same time.

EDIT: You don't have a single client connecting to multiple servers, do you?  Note that TCP connections are always bidirectional, so the server process does get feedback if a client disconnects.  Some internet providers have even been caught generating RST packets on connections that fail some test for suspicious traffic.

Write a signal handler.  Make sure it uses only raw I/O functions to log problems (open, write, close, not `fwrite`, not `printf`).

Check return values.  Check for negative return value from `write` on a socket, but check all return values.

Comment: thanks for the quick post! ATM the only resource they all seem to share is the DataSource itself, but all that is happening is a fread or a DB poll. In the case of a file, the file itself is appended to by a seperate process as well which does no data sending over sockets; purely data receving then output to file.

will look further into the server code and see if i can find anything.

Comment: I had a similar problem before but realized that the problem had been slightly different. here was what happened in the past:
earlier, the write function actually had a timeout on the epoll_wait for writing. Due to some processing ocurring in the client application, the socket wouldn't "be ready" in time for the timeout, causing a crash. Fix was to set the timout for writing to indefinete (for the time being), and it SEEMED to be resolved.

Comment: in reference to your edit: no, a single client can only connect to a single server. at the tcp level, i understand that there is communication back and forth, but on the application level there isn't any client to server communicatin; its all one-way.

i'm using send() atm, which should be the same thing as write()? is there any difference?

Comment: @Nik: either `send` or `write` can be used to transmit on TCP sockets, the main difference is that `write` doesn't have the flags parameter (which is almost always zero anyway).  You should be checking return values from `send` as well, not only to detect partial sends, but also for errors.

Comment: ok, that's what I thought. 
The current code does check for error codes by seeing it -1 is returned or not, but we don't check for partial-writes. From what I am able to find on the internet, send() will block on partial-writes until the entire amount can be written, and returns -1 only on local errors. As such, we don't handle partial-writes, but this could my deeply flawed understanding. Please let me know if i'm wrong about this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments and suggestions.
After looking through the code and adding the signal handling as Ben suggested, the applications themselves are far more stable. Thank you for all your input.

The original problem, however, was due to a rogue script that one of the admins was running as root that would randomly kill certain processes on the server-side machine (i won't get into what it was trying to do in reality; safe to say it was buggy). 
Lesson learned: check the environment.

Thank you all for the advice.